# How do I simply clear a table before importing data?

Tags: ssis

Why is it so difficult to figure out how to clear out data from a table before an import? Could someone please point me in the right direction for a standard, best practice procedure for doing so within SSIS 2012? I've used basic SQL statements; i.e. Delete Tablename, TRUNCATE tablename, etc...

Comment: What do you mean? How is it difficult to figure out how to clear out a table? Execute SQL task allows you to perform any basic SQL operation such as truncating the table. I would recommend a quick google search before posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an [Execute SQL Task](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx&ei=AWXdUcWVJIz88QSMlYGADQ&v6u=https://s-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com/gen_204?ip=207.114.139.254&ts=1373463810022618&auth=cpup5lhtclqdhhq26grb53lkmrbiy6xm&rndm=0.8515305176842958&v6s=2&v6t=1299&usg=AFQjCNEpEdSfn_umEwNWVRyy6i4ieUPR0g&sig2=M493O0ZqxVXs1JUP4tKbzw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.eWU) to do this. Put your truncate or delete from statement in the SQLStatement property. Also, as Lamark stated, you may want to ensure that the task's "Result Set" property is set to none since you are having trouble with errors being returned due to the result bindings.

Comment: Thank you, but if i do just delete tablename, i get "[Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

Comment: Did you type "delete from tablename" or just "delete tablename". Make sure to add "from" in your statement. But I would really just use the truncate in this scenario, especially if you're removing all of the data.

Comment: I have used "Delete dbo.tablename", "delete from tablename", delete * from tablename".right now its "[Execute SQL Task] Error: The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results." 
but i'm using that result binding name  4:35 PM
This is what i'm trying http://irfansworld.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/how-to-truncate-and-load-a-table-from-ssis/ 
Which seems extremely goldbergish, but that's all i could find

Comment: @Paynetech The "execute SQL task" has a "Result Set" property, you need to choose "none" there.

Comment: First of DO NOT do a `DELETE dbo.Tablename` as you will erase the table from existance. Bam Poof gone. Second if you are deleting all records then you want to do a `Truncate Tablename`. Next in you execute SQL task have you set which database you are looking to truncate from.

Comment: Yes, it was the Result Set property that was throwing me off. Thank you everyone! SSIS can be tricky, and i'm just new to it. Thank you @Lamak

Answer (score 0):

Related to best practice, I usually follow the practice of doing as much at the SQL level as you can. The Execute SQL Task as @jymbo advises would likely be the best course of action even it there was a means to truncate within SSIS itself.

Answer (score 0):

@Paynetech - Sorry this question was down-voted as this seemingly simple task was throwing me off when trying to create an SSIS project myself.  And since I have to post this as an answer as I can't comment to your original question, here is some additional information to read that helped me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/d69f2598-3f95-41f1-bd86-da46e9b6d18b/want-to-delete-records-from-table-using-ssis

By the way, when searching google for "ssis how to delete" - this question is #2, #1 being how to delete an SSIS package itself.